# erl_tar can't extract files made with make_tar

Tags: erlang, extract, tar

I'm putting a release file together, which seems to work fine

```
1> systools:make_tar("rel/project-1.0").
ok
```

at that point, I get the expected file at `rel/project-1.0.tar.gz`, however, trying to extract it errors for some reason

```
2> erl_tar:extract("rel/project-1.0.tar.gz").
{error,bad_header}
```

Trying to extract the same file with `tar` from shell, or with the equivalent `os:cmd/1` call, works fine. What's going wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The archive is gzip compressed (notice the `.gz` extension). You will need to use [`extract/2`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl_tar.html#extract-2) and provide the `compressed` option:

```
erl_tar:extract("rel/project-1.0.tar.gz", [compressed]);
```